# TypeError: 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe of float features without my target, so I can further manipulate with them.

I've tried:

```
float_col = data.select_dtypes('float').drop(['TARGET'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Remove sparse numerical features
for f in float_col:
   if data[f].isnull().sum() / data.shape[0] > 0.1667: del data[f] #Remove above 1/6 of NANs
```

...which returns:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I've also tried to do:

```
float_col = data.select_dtypes('float').drop(['TARGET'], axis=1, inplace=True).update()
```

...which returned:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

I believe the issue is caused by the target drop.

Comment: when you use `inplace=True` the operation happens inplace and there is no return value.To assign the result to a variable, just remove the `inplace=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call methods that apply changes *in place*, `None` is returned. You used `.drop(..., inplace=True)`:

```
data.select_dtypes('float').drop(['TARGET'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

so the result of `data.select_dtypes(...)` is directly changed and `None` is assigned to `float_col`. You can't use iteration (like a `for` loop) on `None`.

From the [`DataFrame.drop()` method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

> **inplace** : *bool, default False*
>
> If `True`, do operation inplace and return `None`.

If you wanted to get all `float` columns except `TARGET`, then just remove `inplace=True`:

```
float_col = data.select_dtypes('float').drop(['TARGET'], axis=1)
```